# issue - How optically place div in middle neck and neck with another div

Tags: html, css

### Can anyone tell me how optically (automatically - without margin,padding fix) place navigation in middle neck and neck with heading h1{O nás}?

What I have

[image: A]

What I want

[image: B]

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="#">O nás</a>
  <a href="#">Otváracie hodiny</a>
  <div class="experiment"></div>
  <a href="#">Cenník</a>
  <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>O nás</h1>
</div>
```

fiddle (with SCSS): https://jsfiddle.net/bsxpp25k/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 levels of flex for this, one for navigation, and another for the left and right sides

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a { text-decoration: none; }

.navigation {
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

  a {
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: grey;
  }

  .experiment {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1rem;
    width: 100px;
  }


.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;

}
.navleft, .navright {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.navleft {
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
.navright {
   justify-content: flex-start;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="navleft">
  <a href="#">O nás</a>
  <a href="#">Otváracie hodiny</a>
   </div>
  <div class="experiment"></div>
  <div class="navright">
  <a href="#">Cenník</a>
  <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>O nás</h1>
</div>
```

I am using a flex basis of 0px to make both elements to grow, starting from the same value, so that they are always of the same width.

Notice that setting the flexbasis to a given value, the same for both elements, is not reliable when the have to shrink. See the following snippet, and check the dimensions, they are different

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a { text-decoration: none; }

.navigation {
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 514px;
}

  a {
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: grey;
  }

  .experiment {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1rem;
    width: 100px;
  }


.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;

}
.navleft, .navright {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.navleft {
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
.navright {
   justify-content: flex-start;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="navleft">
  <a href="#">O nás</a>
  <a href="#">Otváracie hodiny</a>
   </div>
  <div class="experiment"></div>
  <div class="navright">
  <a href="#">Cenník</a>
  <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>O nás</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me why flex-basis: 0px?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to fix this would be to define a width for the links in the nav.

Add this to your style sheet and adjust as needed. I just set at 150px for demonstration purposes.

```
.navigation a {
   width: 150px;
   text-align: center;
}
```